# how can i update MVC models's particular field in tables using json array

Tags: json, liferay

```
String expenseIds = resourceRequest.getParameter("expenseIds");
                JSONArray expenseArray = JSONFactoryUtil.createJSONArray(expenseIds);
                LOG.info("JSON ARRAY" + expenseArray);
                if (Validator.isNotNull(expenseIds)) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < expenseArray.length(); i++) {
                        LOG.info("Expense Id"+expenseArray.getInt(i));  
                    }
```

This is my code and i am able to get expenseIds. and I want to update particular field using arrays id

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please give a better explanation of what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I wan to update my database table field for that particulars Ids that i can get inside json array.. - Thank you for comment

Answer (score 0):

## Liferay ORM

Liferay uses ORM which means that you define your objects in service.xml and as part of the build process Liferay creates the objects, the persistence layer, and a utility method for accessing that persistence layer.

Assuming you have an *expense* object, defined below

```
<service-builder package-path="com.latham.request">
    <entity name="Expense" local-service="true" remote-service="true">
        <column name="expenseId" type="long" primary="true" />
    </entity>
</service-builder>
```

To update that you would essentially do something like the following

```
Expense e = ExpenseLocalServiceUtil.getExpense(id);
e.setWhateverAttribute("helloWhateverAttribute");
ExpenseLocalServiceUtil.updateExpense(e);
```

Comment: yes i already have expense entity and expense id column.. By the way, Thanks for the help :-)

Comment: Did you get it to work or do you need something else?